# Can Outlook be configured to send SMSes via Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, sms

Gmail allows sending SMSes through its chat.  Outlook 2007 and 2010 allow sending SMSes from Outlook using an SMS provider.  Is there any way to specify that Gmail should be the SMS provider?

Comment: Wow, this is the second oldest available 'Tumbleweed' awarded question... Is this solved?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't know if you can still send SMS messages through gmail chat, aka hangouts.